# Unable to install AWS CLI on a Mac

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am unable to install AWS CLI on MacBook Yosemite.

I get an error with the `sudo` command from AWS Documentation.

I initially installed `sudo` using the default python2.7, and then tried to install with python3.7 but it doesn't work. I feel it's the folder path that is incorrect but I don't know what to check on it.

Can I get some guidance?

Here is the error output:

```
MacBks-MBP:~ MacBkyosemite$ sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
Password:
Running cmd: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 virtualenv.py --no-download --python /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/aws
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/MacBkyosemite/awscli-bundle/packages/setup setuptools_scm-1.15.7.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 151, in main
    pip_install_packages(opts.install_dir)
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 114, in pip_install_packages
    pip_script, setup_requires_dir, package
  File "awscli-bundle/install", line 49, in run
    p.returncode, cmd, stdout + stderr))
__main__.BadRCError: Bad rc (1) for cmd '/usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/MacBkyosemite/awscli-bundle/packages/setup setuptools_scm-1.15.7.tar.gz': b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/aws/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>\n    from pip import main\nImportError: cannot import name \'main\' from \'pip\' (/Users/MacBkyosemite/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/__init__.py)\n'

MacBks-MBP:~ MacBkyosemite$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3

MacBks-MBP:~ MacBkyosemite$ pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 from /Users/MacBkyosemite/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

MacBks-MBP:~ MacBkyosemite$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 4):

To install the [AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on a Mac, simply run:

```
sudo pip3 install awscli
```

**Tip:** It is normally a good idea to use virtual environments when installing Python libraries to avoid conflicts. In such cases, start a virtual environment, then run `pip`.

Comment: pip doesn't come as default package in mac, to install you can use brew https://brew.sh/